# Is there any AMQP iOS client available which supports AMQP 0-10 version?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, amqp, qpid

I am trying to get information about any iOS client that supports AMQP 0-10 version. I am using Qpid broker 6.0.4 with AMQP 0-10 and looking for a compatible iOS client (Objective-c or Swift).